# How in CIL (MSIL) "call instance void valuetype [..type]" return or save value? (Common Intermediate Language)

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

I am creating an .Net intermediate code emulator that executes CIL instruction after instruction.
I'm having trouble emulating the `call instance void valuetype` more precisely with saving its result

I have C# code :`DateTime? startDate = DateTime.Now;`

that's compiled to:

```
IL_010d: ldloca.s     startDate
IL_010f: call         valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
IL_0114: call         instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime>::.ctor(!0/*valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime*/)
```

- on `IL_010d` - `ldloca` push on stack reference to local variable `startDate`
- on `IL_010f` - `call` push on stack valuetype DateTime==Now

**My first question is: what happen on `IL_0114`**? What the stack should look like after executing the call method? How will the `DateTime.Now` value be entered into the local `startData` variable and at what point?

Alternative if I change C# code to `DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;` (without ?)
is compiled to:

```
IL_010d: call         valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()
IL_0112: stloc.2      // startDate
```

- on `IL_010d` - `call` push value on to the stack
- on `IL_0112` - `stloc` pop value from stack and save in local variable

In this case, everything is clear to me. i.e. after executing the block, there is no object on the stack and `DateTime.Now` has been written to the local variable `startDate`.

**My second question is what is the difference between these two calls?**
`call instance void valuetype`(IL_0114) vs `call valuetype`(IL_010d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "`call instance void valuetype`". There is only `call` and the rest is a method reference.

In the case of the simpler code, `valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime [mscorlib]System.DateTime::get_Now()` is the method reference, but `valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime` is just part of the return type (having `valuetype` to indicate an unboxed form of the type, as opposed to `boxed` or `class`).

After the call to `get_Now`, the value gets to the stack. However, when you convert it to a variable of type `Nullable<DateTime>`, you actually call its constructor which takes care of properly initializing the value.

The method that is called here is `` instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime>::.ctor(!0) ``, i.e. the constructor. Every constructor actually returns `void`, so without any special instruction, the stack is empty after the call, and since the method is also `instance`, it needs a `this` reference. Again `valuetype` here indicates that you are calling the method on an unboxed value of the type.

This is one of the common ways to initialize a value type when its storage location is already allocated. You simply obtain its address and call the constructor in-place, as opposed to using `newobj`. Similarly, the `initobj` instruction zero-initializes it, as if the default constructor had been called.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that by adding the symbol **?** to the variable declaration you are setting its type to **[Nullable<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1)** as opposed to simply `System.DateTime`.  Basically the two declarations below are equivalent:

```
DateTime? d1 = DateTime.Now;
System.Nullable<DateTime> d1 = DateTime.Now;
```

So:

**IL_010d** pushes the address of local variable (`startDate`) to the stack

**IL_010f** pushes the result of `DateTime.Now` to the stack

**IL_0114** calls `Nullable<DateTime>` constructor (using the address of `startDate` as **this**) passing the result of `DateTime.Now` (which initializes `startDate`)

Adriano

Comment: so in IL_0114 - I get two data from the stack - the first is this, which was 'initiated' by the value in IL_010d (does not require newobj).
The second is datetime with the value Now. Calling the constructor for a value variable changes the value of the variable itself?

Comment: does not require newobj) : exactly. In this case the value type is allocated in the stack, instead of in the heap and so no need to use  *newobj* instruction.

"Calling the constructor for a value variable changes the value of the variable itself": A ctor (constructor) is a method which may also have side effects as any other method.